# uninstall old version python (fedora)

Tags: python, fedora

i need to install python 3.2 but i have python 2.7 installed already on fedora 16.
I download python 3.2 and installed it but when i run this command:

```
>python
```

I got:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jul 24 2012, 11:41:34) 
[GCC 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

How can i remove or uninstall this version?

Comment: For most Linux distros, Python 2.x is still an integral part of their system.  You don't want to cause system instability by ripping out Python 2.x and putting Python 3.x in there, since it's not backwards compatible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default python in Fedora is still python 2.x (see [here](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Python3)). So you need to type "python3" to start the 3.x interpreter.  It is not a good idea to remove python 2.x from your Fedora installation because there are likely a number of system functions that use/require python 2.x.  If you really want to be able to just type "python" to run the 3.x interpreter, I recommend that you modify the `.bash_login` file in your home directory to make `python` an alias to the default python 3 interpreter in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: remove all the “probably”s from your answer, it's all correct.

Comment: @bogatron  and if i want to run this command: python setup.py install ? Do i have to replace by python3 setup.py install?

Comment: Yes you need to use "python3" if you want a module installed for python 3 (unless you set up the alias, as I described).

Comment: @JonasWielicki - Good point.  Done.

Comment: When i run it i got this error:`File "setup.py", line 36
    print "Fatal error: bitness cannot be detected!"
                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax` WHat can i do?

Comment: Is this error while installing python3 or while installing a module *for* python3? If it is the latter, you should open a new question.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The question was how to uninstall an ancient and EOL version of python.

Answer (score 3):

You don't, unless you want to break your system. Install the `python3` package from the repositories and invoke it as `python3`.