# Python 3.5.0 gives an unexpected magic number

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, fedora, fedora-25

The following code is a part of a linear equation solver. It is written for python 3. Before running the program it checks the magic number from `imp.get_magic()` against an expected value.

I have Python 3.5.0 installed on a system running Fedora 25.
The problem is that, on my system I get a different value for the magic number.

Expected is : `b'\xf8\x0c\r\n'`

Instead, I get: `b'\x16\r\r\n'`

Here is the code

```
def _get_module():
    del globals()['_get_module']
    import imp
    import base64
    import marshal

    magic = imp.get_magic()
    if magic == b'\xf8\x0c\r\n': # Python 3.5
      pycData = <certain value>
    pycData = base64.decodebytes(pycData)
```

Since I get a different value for the magic number, I can't run this program.

This code is from resources of the book [Coding the Matrix](http://resources.codingthematrix.com/). It can be found under the section "The Matrix" and the file is named [`solver.py`](http://resources.codingthematrix.com/solver.py) (file downloads directly).

Is there a way to get this rolling?

Comment: Well, can't you just make the conditional to be true? What's this code suppose to be doing anyway?

Comment: Oh boy, so the script contains embedded bytecode keyed to the magic number of a Python version and just loads that. What could possibly go wrong?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Has it got something to do with the OS?

Comment: @user3620605: the magic number can change with minor Python version updates too. It changed for 3.5.2; I suspect that that's the magic number you see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic number is updated each time bytecode changes, to make sure that you don't try to load backwards-incompatible bytecode into an older interpreter.

The specific magic marker that code looks for is the one for Python 3.5a0, see the [changelog for markers](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py#L225-L229):

```
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\xf8\x0c', 'little')
3320
```

while you were trying to load this with 3.5b2 or later (but before 3.5.2):

```
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\x16\r', 'little')
3350
```

You can just load that version into 3.5.2; just disable the magic marker tests or rework the code to extract the marker (like I did above, first two bytes) and match the maximum possible value.

I'm not sure why that code is not just distributing a `.pyc` file in the first place however. Python 3.3 bytecode loads just fine into Python 3.6.
I've loaded all versions into Python 3.6, ran `dis.dis()` on each and found *no real differences in the bytecode*.

Comment: I'm using fedora 25, which came with python 3.5.2, I didn't uninstall it(3.5.2) because the answers to this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661487/uninstall-old-version-python-fedora, warns that it may break the system. So I installed 3.5.0 over the existing version, the IDLE shell and python terminal show the version as 3.5.0. 
So you're right about the version 3.5.2, that was what I had on my system.

Comment: Older bytecode versions load *just fine*. They will not break your system.

Comment: The other post warns about replacing the system Python 2 with Python 3, which would indeed be a problem, but that's easily avoided by installing both. Those issues don't apply here.